# Center and scale (responsive!) div-wrapper with several divs inside

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I’m a little stuck on this problem.

What already works:

I’ve got one large div inside my body (and also inside main, just out of css-reasons), which contains eight smaller divs in four columns. I use `float:left;` on my divs, so they appear side by side. I also could do this via `display:inline-block;`. The large div has 100% width, the smaller divs should automatically fill these 100%. Two of the four columns consist of one div with `height:100%;` and two columns hold two divs one below the other, each div has height:50%.

What does not work:

I want these divs to always be side by side, there should never be a line-break, no matter which resolution or device-orientation.

So please help me to center that large div horizontally (and if possible vertically) (I absolutely don't know, why `margin:0 auto;` does not work here) and please tell me, why responsive resizing of the divs (to fill 100% width of the outer div, responsive to the viewport) does not work or where’s my failure.

EDIT: The inner divs (with images inside) should only be scaled proportional, so if there's less viewport-height than image height, the outer div should be scaled down horizontally. In other words, I want to see all my divs, side by side, in their right proportions, no matter which resolution/orientation.

PS: The four columns are not always the same width (not all have 25% of the outer div).

Here is a link to jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/hLzoxmyb/1/

Here is the HTML code:

```
<body>
    <main>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="one">
                <figure id="one">
                    <img src="01.png" alt="01">
                </figure>
            </div>
            <div id="two">
                <figure id="02">
                    <img src="02.png" alt="02">
                </figure>
                <figure id="03">
                    <a href="03.html"><img src="03.png" alt="03"></a>
                </figure>
            </div>
            <div id="three">
                <figure id="04">
                    <a href="04.html"><img src="04.png" alt="04"></a>
                </figure>
                <figure id="05">
                    <a href="05.html"><img src="05.png" alt="05"></a>
                </figure>
            </div>
            <div id="four">
                <figure id="06">
                    <a href="06.html"><img src="06.png" alt="06"></a>
                </figure>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
</body>
```

And here is the CSS code:

```
body {
    background-color:#cccccc;
    font-family: monospace;
    font-size:120%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    width:100%;
}

div#one figure, div#four figure {
    height:80%;
    height:80vh;
}

div#two figure, div#three figure {
    height:40%;
    height:40vh;
}

figure {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

div#wrapper {
    padding-bottom:10%;
    padding-bottom:10vh;
    padding-top:10%;
    padding-top:10vh;
}

div#wrapper div {
    float:left;
}

div#wrapper div figure img, div#wrapper div figure a img {
    height:100%;
}

main {
    /*
    bottom:0;
    display:block;
    left:0;
    margin:auto;
    max-height:100%;
    max-height:100vh;
    max-width:100%;
    max-width:100vw;
    overflow:auto;
    position:fixed;
    right:0;
    top:0;
    */
    margin:0 auto;
    width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`display: inline-block;` along with `white-space: nowrap;` aligns them side-by-side without wrapping.

http://jsfiddle.net/hLzoxmyb/2/

I did not understand the second part of your question. If you clarify, I'll update my answer.

Edit: Adding a couple of % width rules gets rid of the scrolling by scaling down the content of the `#wrapper`.

http://jsfiddle.net/hLzoxmyb/5/

Edit: Specifying the `#wrapper`'s width with `margin: 0 auto;` centers it.

http://jsfiddle.net/hLzoxmyb/6/

Comment: Thanks! I’ll try to clarify my approach: I don't want no line-break or scrollability on this site, instead the div should be scaled down/up to `width:100%;`/`width:100vw%;`. So probably I can't even use `height` on my elements, but I would have to use `max-height` or something like that instead. Did that already clarify things?

Comment: When saying “the div” I mean `div#wrapper`. So all inner div elements plus its figures, anchors and images should have a width of max 100% of the viewport / 100vw.

Comment: Thanks! That almost works perfectly. It would, if all four divs/images would be the same width, they are all a little different, so not each div should have exactly one-fourth of 100%. Is there a way to achief this, or not? And, how would I center the wrapper-div? (E.g. if the div would have 80% of width (instead of 100%), that would be important.) Thanks!

Comment: Oh, at first I also thought of when rescaling the viewport in height, the content of div#wrapper should be scaled proportional. But then we could ne use a static width-value for div#wrapper, hm.

Comment: Oh, I tried `margin:0 auto;` on main. Sorry. I meant this solution would work perfectly, if the four divs would have the same width. But in my example they don't have the same width. Altogether, thought, shall be 100% of the outer div. Also I am talking about maintaining aspect ratio when saying scaling proportional, yes. Thanks so far very much!

Comment: Nope, that’s not the point. I minimalized the fiddle to ease things up.

Comment: In my project, the four columns have different widths. And as there are images/illustrations/photographs in there, they have to be scaled maintaining aspect ratio. I’m really sorry for the confusion!